# Topological sort (Kahn's algorithm) trouble

Tags: python, algorithm, topological-sort

I am having trouble wrapping my head around my code in the nested for loop. I am following the Kahn's algorithm here on wiki: [Kahn's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). I don't understand how to test for if outgoingEdge has incoming edges for each endArray element (m).

Here is what I have so far:

```
    def topOrdering(self, graph):

    retList = []
    candidates = set()
    left = []
    right = []

    for key in graph:
        left.append(key)
        right.append(graph[key])

    flattenedRight = [val for sublist in right for val in sublist]

    for element in left:
        if element not in flattenedRight:
            #set of all nodes with no incoming edges
            candidates.add(element)

    candidates = sorted(candidates)

    while len(candidates) != 0:
        a = candidates.pop(0)
        retList.append(a)
        endArray = graph[a]

        for outGoingEdge in endArray:

            if outGoingEdge not in flattenedRight:
                candidates.append(outGoingEdge)
                #flattenedRight.remove(outGoingEdge)

            del outGoingEdge


    if not graph:
        return "the input graph is not a DAG"
    else:
        return retList
```

Here is a picture visualizing my algorithm. Graph is in a form of an adjacency list. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store [indegree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) (number of incoming edges) separately and decrement the count every time you remove a vertex from empty set. When count becomes 0 add the vertex to empty set to be processed later. Here's example:

```
def top_sort(adj_list):
    # Find number of incoming edges for each vertex
    in_degree = {}
    for x, neighbors in adj_list.items():
        in_degree.setdefault(x, 0)
        for n in neighbors:
            in_degree[n] = in_degree.get(n, 0) + 1

    # Iterate over edges to find vertices with no incoming edges
    empty = {v for v, count in in_degree.items() if count == 0}

    result = []
    while empty:
        # Take random vertex from empty set
        v = empty.pop()
        result.append(v)

        # Remove edges originating from it, if vertex not present
        # in adjacency list use empty list as neighbors
        for neighbor in adj_list.get(v, []):
            in_degree[neighbor] -= 1

            # If neighbor has no more incoming edges add it to empty set
            if in_degree[neighbor] == 0:
                empty.add(neighbor)

    if len(result) != len(in_degree):
        return None # Not DAG
    else:
        return result

ADJ_LIST = {
    1: [2],
    2: [3],
    4: [2],
    5: [3]
}

print(top_sort(ADJ_LIST))
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention, no empty keys allowed.

Comment: @JeffreyPhung What do you mean no empty keys allowed? `3` shouldn't be in adjacency list because there's no outgoing edges?

Comment: My adjacency list given doesn't have 3 included. So from your logic, there will be an exception error, which is the reason why I tried to do it my way. From your way, I guess I would have to then create another adjacency list for every neighbor again?

Comment: @JeffreyPhung In that case you can make minor change and use empty list as default neighbors and compare the result length to indegree instead of adjacency list. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! Definitely better than how I wanted to do it.